# How to Trigger IsFocused on DatePickerTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I set the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property via a `DataTrigger`. The template includes the `Border` around my `DatePicker` and second `Border` with a `TextBlock` inside.

I am trying to visible the second `Border` when `DatePickerTextBox` `IsFocused` property is `True` only.

Below my code I have so far (it is just a shortened version):

```
<Style x:Key="CustomDatePickerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                <Border Background="{DynamicResource Control.Background}" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3">
                        <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                        <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Height="14" Margin="3 0 0 0" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" 
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <DatePickerTextBox.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" Opacity="1">
                                        <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                            <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"/>
                                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </DatePickerTextBox.Template>
                        </DatePickerTextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border Background="{DynamicResource Control.Validation.Background}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Control.Validation.Border}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" >
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Padding="3 0 3 0" Foreground="{DynamicResource Control.Validation.Foreground}" Margin="1"/>
                                            <Border.Style>
                                                <Style>
                                                    <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AdornedElement.(DatePicker.IsFocused), ElementName=textBox}" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Border.Style>
                                        </Border>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I think it is possible by accessing via `ElementName = PART_TextBox, Path=IsFocused` but I always get the `Error`: *PART_TextBox not found*

Comment: Why are you binding to IsReadOnly? Do you see the Validation.ErrorTemplate?

Comment: because I have two custom controls bound to the same value .. i want that the custom control which is read-only does not have a validation template.. I just want that the Trigger for the Border.Visibility triggers when the logical focus is on the DatePickerTextBox

Comment: @mm8 sorry for not answering the second question .. yes i see the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` but it doesn't stay open when I click on the `DatePickerTextBox`. The `ErrorTemplate` appears only when I hover the `Control`

Comment: Please provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker also has a `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` Property which is True if the focus is in the Textbox of the DatePicker. This helps out, i had the same problem.

```
<Style TargetType="DatePicker">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```